# Http requests suddenly not working

Tags: java, php, android, json, mysqli

I'm developing two apps which make use of the same online server to access mysqli databases. Up to a few moments ago they both worked fine, however now they're both crashing with a null exception when I use a http get request to load data in JSON format from my database. I checked online to see what the response is and instead of seeing the JSON data that has always been loaded I suddenly see this. I'm not sure if the server has made some changes or what's going on but I can't load any data from my online databases as it stands.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Checking your browser..
      <h2>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
        <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
          <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("7c1b95c2ae1fc0d11f10c396f4889bf1");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://****?ckattempt=1";
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

EDIT

Asynctask which makes request ( pretty standard and worked perfectly fine before; issue not in code)

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_gamess, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Questions:", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Games
                    allquestions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GAMELIST);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < allquestions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = allquestions.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String zadanie = c.getString(TAG_ZADANIE);
                        String odp_a = c.getString(TAG_ODP_A);
                        String odp_b = c.getString(TAG_ODP_B);
                        String odp_c  = c.getString(TAG_ODP_C);
                        String odp_d = c.getString(TAG_ODP_D);
                        String commentfirst = c.getString(TAG_COMMENTFIRST);
                        String comment = c.getString(TAG_COMMENT);
                        String correctanswer = c.getString(TAG_CORRECTANSWER);
                        Log.d("id",id);
                        Log.d("zadanie",zadanie);
                        Log.d("ansa",odp_a);
                        Log.d("ansb",odp_b);
                        Log.d("ansc",odp_c);
                        Log.d("comment",comment);
                        Log.d("correctans",correctanswer);
                        Log.d("commentfirst",commentfirst);


                        questionabcd a = new questionabcd(zadanie,odp_a,odp_b,odp_c,odp_d,correctanswer,comment,commentfirst);
                        Log.d("questionabcd", a.toString());
                        // creating new HashMap

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        questions.add(a);

                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }
```

ERROR :

```html
08-08 15:52:18.714  28394-28476/com.example.albert.mathapp E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
08-08 15:52:18.754  28394-28476/com.example.albert.mathapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.albert.mathapp, PID: 28394
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity$LoadAllQuestions.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94)
            at com.example.albert.mathapp.MainActivity$LoadAllQuestions.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:70)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: 'crashing with a null exception'??? What is a null exception? 'when I use a http get request'. Where, when and how are you using that?

Comment: A null exception as in my android app does not receive any data from the http request, so it throws a null exception when I try to manipulate it. I didn't make any changes to my code in either of the apps and it worked perfectly fine up till now, so it isn't an issue with my code. I'm assuming I need to pass some kind of parameter to identify myself for the server if they made changes which require this now.

Comment: Null exceptions do not exist. Thats why i asked. And what is 'it' in 'when i try to manupilate it'?

Comment: What server is you db hosted on?

Comment: See, you're focusing on my code when I'm telling you this is explicitly a server issue.  It refers to the JSON data which my get request fetches. Like I said, my code is not the issue here. As you can see, when using Advanced REST Client the response has changed, instead of sending the JSON data, I receive this which is what's causing the errors in my app. @Maverick283 byethost.

Comment: well, I gotta be honest, I do not really have an idea, only assumptions based on the information you give: I agree, this probably is a server issue. They have changed something on the server side, which makes your http request send back something different, rather then what you are used to. The code you pasted looks like a ddos saftey or anything in that direction. You probably need a different http request. As @mankee pointed out, you need to add more code for us to understand what you are doing and to help you out adjust the code so it works with the changed server again.

Comment: As long as you can't change what is on the server you won't be able to resolve the problem without changing your code!

Comment: So what code which you like to see? The asynctask which makes the request?

Comment: `See, you're focusing on my code when I'm telling you this is explicitly a server issue.`. No it's a question of bad coding when you get a `NullPointerException`. Why do you keep talking of a 'null exception'? You should check the json result for null and not continue in your code if that `pointer` is `null`. Further you should dig deeper in your code to see the actual error/exception. Most certainly you use that jsonparser that retirns null always when there are exceptions.

Comment: @greenapps Once again, I got over a dozen asynctasks which worked before today and stopped working today. The issue is not with the code. The issue is with the changes done to the server. Now unless you have a recommendation as to what I should add to my code to make it work with the changes done, or if you know something about these changes done to the server, your comment about my code is completely useless to me, because as I said repeatedly before, this whole issue has risen due to changes on the server NOT in my code.

Comment: no reason to be rude to @greenapps as he is just trying to help you. And again, he is right: You were assuming that you'll always get the answer you need from that server, not catching any "Null Pointer Exception"s. This is bad coding, no doubt. But it can be fixed, though we need code for that to see what actually causes the error. A list of what we need: The source of the request to the server; The part where it parses the servers response ( and maybe an example of a response that you used to get if you have one); The exception stack trace. With these information we might be able to help you

Comment: @Maverick283 the asynctask which makes the request as well as the stacktrace are posted in the question. The response which I would be getting is a JSON Array, I don't have an example. Please pay close attention to the parameter which I'm passing as the last time I had a similar problem with this server, adding that one line solved the problem.

Comment: You posted the code and the stacktrace but forgot to tell which code line is on `MainActivity.java:94`. But i'm pretty sure it's  `int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);`. As said before: In  `JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest` "json" can be null; So check if it is null and do not continue but return from doInBackground. And also as said before: Now you have to dig deeper in `makeHttpRequest` to see what the actual error/exception is. `Now unless you have a recommendation as to what I should add to my code` .. . I already had given them. And now I repeated them.

Comment: That's line 94 Log.d("All Questions:", json.toString());. You see the issue is very clear. My app is expecting a JSON Array with certain tags and certain data. That was what it was receiving up till now. But now it is receiving what I posted in the question : some kind of html code which is meant to display Checking browser in a browser. It's like if your method is expecting an integer input and you provide it with an Array of strings. It doesn't make sense and it will throw an error. That is why I don't want to look into my code, but I want to see WHY I am suddenly getting HTML not JSON

Comment: No. It will not throw an error. You are causing an exception because you use the pointer json when it is null. You should check if it is null and not use things like json.toString(). Make your code robuust to begin with. `want to see WHY I am suddenly getting HTML not JSON`. You are asking this on a site for programmers? Sorry, wrong site.

Comment: So where do you suggest I should solve this programming issue if not on a site for programmers?

Comment: I am aware that the lack of the check for nullpointerexception is an issue however it is not the issue the question is about and not the issue I'd like to prioritise now.